# Partial deserialization of JSON

Tags: gson

There is a complex JSON that I need to deserialize.
However I need only part of the information there, like 10%.

Is it possible to deserialize only the parts I am interested in, and ignore the rest, i.e. make a model that **defines only some elements**, but not all?
Otherwise it will take a lot of time for me to define the complete model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems this is the default behaviour of GSON, at least version 2.8.0.

So when defining the model, all you need to do is to define the elements that should be deserialized - the rest should be simply omitted and GSON will happily ignore.

*<sup>Maybe I need to delete this question?</sup>*